# Null pointer Exception when writing a function for deleting a node at a specific position from a linked list in java

Tags: java

Below are my lines of code for deleting a node from a linked list.

```
Node Delete(Node head, int position) {
  // Complete this method
    int pos = 0;
    Node current = head;
    Node previous = null;

    if(position == 0 && head.next == null){
        return null;
    }

    if(head==null){
        return null;
    }

    while(current.next!=null){
        pos = pos + 1;
        current = current.next;
        if(pos==position){
            previous.next = current.next;

        }
        previous = current;

    }
    return head;


}
```

What I am currently trying to do is declare two nodes current and previous. I initialized current to the head node of the linked list and previous to null. I have two if statements to deal with the tricky situation like the head being null and there being only one node in the linked list.

In the while loop, I have codes that is supposed to delete nodes other than in that in position 0. With the two nodes that I have declared above, I am simply trying to delete the node at certain position by setting up the previous pointer to point to the next node of current node.

However it's giving me a null pointer exception and I have gone out of ideas to see what actually went wrong to give me such an error. Any help from this community will be very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: @Joe C I have already tried using debugger. I heard that the simplest debugging technique is to use print statement which I already tried. Conceptually what I am trying to do makes sense however, what going wrong is that my code is not working. So you could point out the line where I got it all wrong.

Comment: No, I will not.  First of all, you haven't even described what's wrong.  Second of all, Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a debugging service.  If the simple debugging techniques don't work, you will have to take it up a level, as described in detail in the link I have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the other peer's comments for future community interactions.

Your problem is that you are not stopping the loop when you find the position:

```
Node Delete(Node head, int position) {
  // Complete this method
    int pos = 0;
    Node current = head;
    Node previous = null;

    if(position == 0 && head.next == null){
        return null;
    }

    if(head==null){
        return null;
    }

    while(current.next!=null){
        pos = pos + 1;
        current = current.next;
        if(pos==position){
            previous.next = current.next;
            break; // Terminate the Loop
        }
        previous = current;

    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: I am still getting Null Pointer Exception. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: try harder and use a debugger!

Comment: What kind of debugger do you suggest? @Miguel

Comment: Jet Brain IntelliJ or Eclipse